# Android - New calendar style DatePicker and TimePicker

Tags: android, calendar, datepicker, timepicker

Is it possible to use the new `DatePickerDialog` and `TimePickerDialog` style used in the latest version of android? They can be seen here : [New style Date and time pickers](http://9to5google.com/2013/05/30/google-calendar-for-android-updated-with-custom-colors-redesigned-datetime-pickers/)

I tried looking for the latest sources of the AOSP Project, but event with that code, I still get the old one (With spinners) - They use the same `DatePickerDialog` and `TimePickerDialog` classes, so I was not expecting anything else.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For future reference, the BetterPickers library has added support for the Google Now and Google Calendar date and time pickers from AOSP.

https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers/

I have not been able to properly implement the library tyczj suggested, and the test APK for it even causes an ANR. Better Pickers seems more stable.

Might be worth checking out both if anyone else wants to implement this.

Comment: This seems not to be maintained anymore.

Comment: Ya thats right. Also its no longer working with API 21

Comment: They seems to have fixed compatibility with API21.

Answer (score 13):

there is a [DatePicker](https://github.com/biboune/datetimepicker) library that looks just like that

Comment: Is'nt there a way to use the one from Google ?

Comment: what is the difference its the same thing

Comment: Yeah but TimePicker is not ready in this lib. (Currently working on the TimePicker)

Comment: well if google has not submitted the code to AOSP (I personally have not checked myself) for you to pull it from, then you ont be able to use it so you have no choice right now

Comment: I tought that being used in the app made it AOSP.

Comment: the calendar app is in the AOSP but if they did not commit the code then how can you get it?

Comment: At what frequency do they make commit ?

Comment: The AOSP calendar app is not updated anymore. That's why Calendar appeared in the Play Store.