# New TimePicker Dialog like Google Agenda App

Tags: android, time, dialog

I looking on google but i don't find informations about this.

I would implement this Widget

http://mysmarttransport.fr/api_dialog_timer.png

Do you think this API is own by google or is included in Android SDK ?

Thanks to help me !

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that is available in the SDK now.
However a similar question has been asked before.

[Android - New calendar style DatePicker and TimePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578856/android-new-calendar-style-datepicker-and-timepicker)
It provides links to these that have a similar layout to the new Google Time Picker Dialog.
https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers/
https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker

Hope that helps.