# Android studio TimePicker and DatePicker

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to set the date/time shown on a date picker or time picker which the user can then edit? I have looked on the android developer console and found nothing but i was wondering if there was still a way?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers) coming from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20223949/316555)

Comment: yes. Store the selected data/time in a `Calender` instance and then set that to the date/time picker next time the user opens it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, `TimePicker` and `DatePicker` classes have the appropriate setters to set the desired time/date after you have instantiated them.

example:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

timePicker1 = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1); //supposed you have defined the "timePicker1" id in your layout xml
timePicker1.setCurrentHour(hour);
timePicker1.setCurrentMinute(minute);
```

Comment: What about for datepicker? i got the timepicker to work but not for datepicker, there is not function for setting the date

Comment: @ElliotArcher Read the DatePicker api for the init method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html

Answer (score 0):

try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czKLAx750N0) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDAjPcXRZho)

I think you must have a datepicker and timepicker in different parts